# But now he has come to

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, adverbs

In the Orient Long Man's dictionary Word Master I have found the different uses of  ' to' - as a preposition, to infinitive and an adverb

The example is given for its use as an adverb

*He was unconscious for some time, but now he has come to* = return to a conscious state.

Native speakers can understand its meaning but non native speakers of English can not understand What  "come to" means

What is "come to " here? Is it an idiom or something else?

I would like to know how "to" can be used as an adverb in different contexts?

Comment: The meaning is exactly as you described it from the dictionary. I don't think you mean to be asking what it means—because you already *know* what it means—but asking *why* it means that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Come to" is a phrasal verb which means "to become conscious again after an injury or medical operation".

> come to
>
> **phrasal verb** with come   ​
>
> to become conscious again after an accident
>   or operation:
>
> Has he come to yet?

[Come to (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-to)

> In English, a phrasal verb is a phrase such as turn down or ran into
>   which combines two or three words from different grammatical
>   categories: a verb and a particle and/or a preposition together form a
>   single semantic unit. This semantic unit cannot be understood based
>   upon the meanings of the individual parts, but must be taken as a
>   whole.

[Phrasal verb (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb)

Comment: I know the phrasal verbs such as _look after, look into_ which are followed by an object. it seems quite different.

Comment: Not all phrasal verbs are followed by an object, in fact many are not. _Come up, go out, fall over_, are three I just thought of.

Comment: @JagathaVLNarasimharao You may find this link that reviews transitive and intransitive phrasal verbs helpful: https://www.woodwardenglish.com/lesson/transitive-intransitive-phrasal-verbs/